# Remove partially duplicate lines using a Bash script

Tags: bash

I want to remove partially duplicate lines from a text file, e.g:

```html
1 a 123
1 a 456
1 b 999
2 c 678
3 d 888
```

If combination of first and second column is duplicated, I want to remove all of the line from the file.

**Desired output**

```html
1 b 999
2 c 678
3 d 888
```

Is there any possible way to remove the duplicate lines using a Bash script?

Thanks

Comment: If you know the length of the first two columns, you can use [`uniq --check-chars=N`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/uniq1.html) for this.

Comment: Are the duplicates always adjacent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear how your data is delineated - tabs? spaces? # of chars? - but `sort` should be able to get you sorted... :-)

```
sort -u -k1,2 input.txt
```

That will use whitespace as delimiter, so hopefully will solve your problem regardless. Do note that if your data was not in order before then this will change the sort order -- glancing through the man page it was not clear to me whether `--check` would be a solution for this or not...

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

If your data in those 2 fields is guaranteed to be the same number of characters then you could use `uniq -w`:

```
uniq -w 4 input.txt
```

A quick glance through the man page doesn't show an option to ignore fields at the end of the line (`-f...` skips fields at the beginning of the line).

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html

If you don't like the order of your lines being changed by `sort` and you don't have a standard number of characters in those columns for `uniq` then you will need to look at `awk` or `perl`, either of which could probably be done in a 1-liner...

It's been several years since I messed with perl, so this is pretty gross, but it does the job:

```
 perl -e '$l0 = $l1 = ""; while (<>) { @fields = split; print if (@fields[0] != $l0 || @fields[1] != $l1); $l0 = @fields[0]; $l1 = @fields[1]; }' input.txt
```

Awk goes back even more years, but it's probably a better tool than perl as perl is a bit overkill:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { x1 = "xyz"; x2 = "xyz" }
x1 != $1 || x2 != $2 { print "x1="x1 ", 1="$1 ", x2="x2", 2="$2; print $0; x1 = $1; x2 = $2; }' input.txt
```